# search_path setting interaction when set for a function, versus role

Tags: postgresql, security

I have a role called 'kube' with limited grants; those required to call functions in the `api` schema.  This includes access to the "shared" schema that specifies user-defined used in the function parameters.

The kube role has a `search_path` set as follows:

```sql
alter role kube set search_path = api,shared;
```

for each function, grant execute

```sql
grant execute on function api.:fn_name to kube;
```

Is there anything to consider in how I have set the permissions, versus including the following for each function?

```sql
create function... as
$$
...
$$ language plpgsql security definer
      set search_path=api,shared,core,pg_temp;
```